# INSERT multiple rows based on SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008 and with the help of other threads I have been able to write the following:

```
insert into fml0grant (auto_key, roleid)
    select fml0.auto_key, 20 
    from fml0
    left join fml0grant on fml0.auto_key = fml0grant.auto_key
    where fml0.dwgname <> ''
      and fml0grant.roleid is null
```

However what I need to do is insert multiple rows for each record found in the where clause. So when the where clause gets a result I need to insert:

1. fml0.auto_key, 20
2. fml0.auto_key, 508
3. fml0.auto_key, 10

Is there any way to combine all three inserts into one statement as after the first in my query the NULL in the WHERE clause is no longer true.

Comment: This question is not clear to me,please look [here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) on how to improve question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` as the below.

```
insert into fml0grant (auto_key, roleid)
    select fml0.auto_key, V.Id 
    from fml0
    left join fml0grant on fml0.auto_key = fml0grant.auto_key
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES (20),(508),(10)) V (Id)
    where fml0.dwgname <> ''
      and fml0grant.roleid is null
```

Comment: Works a treat, Thanks NEER